# bypassing to_python registry for class exported with class_<>?

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

Here is a boost.python question I couldn't answer using the documentation.

I have two C++ classes A and B, such that B is a subclass of A, and under certain conditions an object of type A can be converted to an object of type B.  Both of these classes are being exported with class_<>.  Schematically:

```
class A 
{ 
public:
    bool is_B() const { ... }    // returns true if conversion to B will succeed
    ...
};

class B : public A {
    B(const A &a) { ... }    // should only be called if a.is_B() == true
    ...
};

class_<A>("A") ... ;
class_<B,bases<A> >("B") ... ;
```

I would like the to-python converter for class A to return an object of class B if possible; otherwise it should return an object of class A.  Schematically:

```
 struct A_to_python_converter {
     PyObject *convert(const A &a) {
         if (a.is_B())
             // return object of class B
             return boost::python::incref(boost::python::object(B(a)).ptr());
         else
             ...  // return object of class A
     }
 }

 boost::python::to_python_converter<A,A_to_python_converter>();
```

The problem is that I'm not sure what code to put in place of the "..." above.  If I put:

```
// return object of class A
return boost::python::incref(boost::python::object(a).ptr());
```

then I get an infinite loop since A_to_python_converter::convert() will be called recursively.  Is there a way to bypass the registry, and convert an object of class A to a (PyObject *) without going through A_to_python_converter, given that A has already been exported with class_<>?  That would solve my problem cleanly (although I'm open to other suggestions).

Thanks!
K

Answer (score 3):

A type is only expected to have a single to-Python conversion registered to it.

When a class is exposed via [`boost::python::class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec), type information and registration occurs.  Additionally, if `boost::noncopyable` is not provided, then to-Python and from-Python converters that will copy `T` by value are registered.  Users can register their own custom converters using [`boost::python::to_python_converter`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/to_python_converter.html).

Hence, one solution is to suppress the default converters for class `A` using `boost::noncopyable`, then register a custom converter that will create Python objects that hold either instances of `A` or instances of `B`.  This approach will use a lower-level API within Boost.Python to handle instance creation.

```cpp
/// @brief Custom converter that converts A to either an A or B Python object.
struct class_A_cref_wrapper
  : boost::python::to_python_converter<A, class_A_cref_wrapper>
{
  // Type that makes instances that hold A by value.
  typedef boost::python::objects::make_instance<A,
        boost::python::objects::value_holder<A>
  > instance_maker;

  static PyObject* convert(const A& a)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    return a.is_B()
      ? python::incref(python::object(B(a)).ptr()) // Create B.
      : instance_maker::execute(boost::ref(a));    // Create A.      
  }
};
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad26655dacfbaaab) this approach:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

// Legacy API.
class A 
{ 
public:
  A() : b_(false)   {}
  A(bool b) : b_(b) {}
  bool is_B() const { return b_; } // true if conversion to B will succeed
private:
  bool b_;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
  B() : A()            {}
  B(const A& a) : A(a) {}
};

/// @brief Factory functions that return an A type with is_B of false.
A make_A() { return A(false); }

/// @brief Factory functions that return an A type with is_B of true.
A make_B() { return A(true);  }

/// @brief Custom converter that converts A to either an A or B Python object.
struct class_A_cref_wrapper
  : boost::python::to_python_converter<A, class_A_cref_wrapper>
{
  // Make and hold instances by value.
  typedef boost::python::objects::make_instance<A,
        boost::python::objects::value_holder<A>
  > instance_maker;

  static PyObject* convert(const A& a)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    return a.is_B()
      ? python::incref(python::object(B(a)).ptr()) // Create B.
      : instance_maker::execute(boost::ref(a));    // Create A.      
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Expose A and B classes.  Use boost::noncopyable to suppress to-Python
  // and from-Python converter regristration for class A.
  python::class_<A, boost::noncopyable>("A");
  python::class_<B, python::bases<A> >("B");

  // Register a custom converter for A.
  class_A_cref_wrapper();

  // Expose factory functions that always return an A type.  This will
  // cause to_python converters to be invoked when invoked from Python.
  python::def("make_A", &make_A);
  python::def("make_B", &make_B);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> assert(isinstance(example.make_A(), example.A))
>>> assert(isinstance(example.make_B(), example.B))
>>> assert(isinstance(example.make_B(), example.A))
>>> assert(not isinstance(example.make_A(), example.B))
```